# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'PostCard Layout' when I am trying to assign it to @Input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm getting the error

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'PostCard Layout'

I have a parent component called `page-blog.component.html` that I am setting the class styles in, and passing them to the child component called `post-card.component.ts`

In my parent HTML component when I try to set the class styling variables from the class component is when it errors out for me. Happening with the `@Input() layout: PostCardLayout;` section.

I found what I would feel as a dirty fix but will prob allow me to make more mistakes in the future by going into to the tsconfig.json file and setting `"strictInputTypes": false,`

Child class `post-card.component.ts`

```
import { Component, HostBinding, Input } from '@angular/core';

 export type PostCardLayout = 'list' | 'grid' | 'grid-sm';

 @Component({
  selector: 'app-post-card',
   templateUrl: './post-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-card.component.scss']
 })
export class PostCardComponent {

@Input() post;

@Input() layout: PostCardLayout;

@HostBinding('class.post-card') classPostCard = true;

@HostBinding('class.post-card--layout--list') get classPostCardLayoutList(): boolean {
  return this.layout === 'list';
}

@HostBinding('class.post-card--layout--grid') get classPostCardLayoutGrid(): boolean {
  return this.layout === 'grid';
}

@HostBinding('class.post-card--layout--grid-sm') get classPostCardLayoutGridSm(): boolean {
  return this.layout === 'grid-sm';
}

constructor() { }
}
```

Here is the parent HTML component `page-blog.component.html`

```
                    <div class="posts-list__body">
                        <div *ngFor="let post of posts" class="posts-list__item">
                            <app-post-card
                                [post]="post"
                                [layout]="{
                                    classic: 'grid',
                                    list: 'list',
                                    grid: 'grid-sm'
                                }"
                            ></app-post-card>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Is that extra [layout] at the end of your string intentional? Have you tried setting layout as a variable for the parent component of app-post-card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typed your PostCardLayout to accept one of three values:

```
'list' | 'grid' | 'grid-sm'
```

You are attempting to pass a JSON object:

```
[layout]="{
          classic: 'grid',
          list: 'list',
          grid: 'grid-sm'
      }[layout]"
```

There also appears to be a typo in that there is an extra `[layout]` at the end of your input.

I'm guessing between the typo and turning off the strictIputTypes your JSON is getting morphed into a string.

using `"strictInputTypes": false` is a terrible idea as this defeats one of the basic purposes of TypeScript.

From what I can tell from your code you want to simply assign one of the three pre-defined values:

```
<app-post-card
      [post]="post"
      [layout]="'grid'">
</app-post-card>
```

Comment: Think you are missing a { before grid?

Comment: so changing it to  `[layout]='"list"'` fixed it.

Comment: you could also more simply write `layout="list"`. Using the angular brackets for the attribute is superfluous in this case as all you are doing is passing an inline string.